Why is phosphoric acid a weak acid?
What is the reason for the phosphoric acid $\ce{H3PO4}$ being a weak acid despite having a structure similar to that of sulfuric acid $\ce{H2SO4}?$
I found some sources claiming that the resonance of one oxygen with double-bonded oxygen blocks the resonance of that of $\ce{OH-},$ destabilising the negative charge. I am not sure about this reason.

Dissociation of H+ ions is less favorable in H3PO4 when compared to H2SO4. One of the central P-OH groups can be in resonance with a neighboring doubly bonded oxygen. This resonance form partially shifts the negative charge away from the OH group, making it slightly less "willing" to release a proton (H+).

About the reason you gave about cross conjugation , it is also present in sulphuric acid. In sulphuric acid it is only from two sides but that is not the main reason why phosphoric acid is weak and sulphuric acid is strong.

Not that it's all that weak, at least in the first dissociation.

To get a systematic idea, also compare $\ce{H2SO4}$ with $\ce{H2SeO4}$, and $\ce{H2S, PH3, HCl, HBr}$. This way, you can separate the influence of electronegativity and the different number of valence electrons. You also see it matter whether the hydrogen is attached to oxygen (in oxyacids) or directly to the central element (in the binary acids).

There are few reasons why $\ce{H3PO4}$ is much weaker acid than $\ce{H2SO4}$:

$\ce{P}$ has much lower electronegativity than $\ce{S}$, leading to making a weaker acid, as it causes lower $\ce{O-H}$ bond polarization.
$\ce{O}$ atoms on a central atom polarize $\ce{HO}$ bonds by induction efect, making the central atom effectively more electronegative. (See acidity raising in order $\ce{HClO}$ < $\ce{HClO2}$ < $\ce{HClO3}$ < $\ce{HClO4}$). $\ce{S}$ in $\ce{H2SO4}$ has one more attached $\ce{O}$ atoms than $\ce{H3PO4}$.
$\ce{O}$ atoms on a central atom make the conjugate base weaker by bigger charge delocalization. ($\ce{HSO4-}$ delocalizes on three $\ce{ O}$ atoms, $\ce{H2PO4-}$ just on two.
Multiple $\ce{OH}$ groups make the acid weaker by increasing electron density on the central atom, making it effectively less electronegative. $\ce{H3PO4}$ has one more.


I would say it's mostly 3rd point. I don't see why 4th would be the case.
